# How to hide window decoration (title bar) in Opera 32 and Cinnamon?

Tags: window-manager, cinnamon, opera, window-decoration, mutter

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and my DE and window manager is Cinnamon (Muffin).

Chromium has a nice option "Use system title bar and borders". Opera does not. I tried to add an option `--force-native-window-frame` to the opera's command line arguments, also tried to install opera-developer.

```
opera-developer --force-native-window-frame=false
```

Unfortunately, it has no effect. Any ideas?